# How to log everything on a Apache server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, logging

I know it seems this has been said 10000 times but I can't have it working:

I've set up the log from my php.ini without luck.
I did these exact steps:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html

> How do I log all php errors to a log fiie?
>
> Just add following line to /etc/php.ini to log errors to specified
>   file – /var/log/php-scripts.log
>   vi /etc/php.ini
>
> Modify error_log directive error_log = /var/log/php-scripts.log
>
> Make sure display_errors set to Off (no errors to end users)
>   display_errors = Off
>
> Save and close the file. Restart web server:
>   /etc/init.d/httpd restart

Then I've tried with htaccess. Not working neither:
http://perishablepress.com/how-to-enable-php-error-logging-via-htaccess/

```
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log

# prevent access to PHP error log
<Files PHP_errors.log>
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy All
</Files>
```

I did it with htaccess and not httpd.conf

Just wanted to ask some help in here.
My problem is that, for some users, when they log in to my app (with phonegap) to my PHP apache server and have a low bandwidth, they receive an error message. I can't reproduce it unfortunately, and would like to know what's going on. I think it's a bad connection error but I'm not sure.

Many Thanks.

Comment: do not forget to look into the error log of the ***webserver*** as well. not all errors go into the php error log, there is more than one component active to handle a users HTTP request. And your users should not see any PHP errors, if they do, you need to disable error reporting.

Comment: are you talking about syslog ? if not, where can I find out more about it ? Many thanks

Comment: I mean the apache error log: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

Comment: Yes I can see error.log in my apache2 folder. That's actually the ONLY logs I have. but I can't see anything from the errors I;m specifying in my post. Therefore I tried with php logs without success. I tried triggering bugs intentionally (function I know would break) but couldn't see them anywhere ...

Comment: if you put a syntax error in your file (for testing), you should see it reported in the php error log. if you don't see it, php error logging is not enabled properly. just create a new php file that only contains an error to test this.